# How do I create views of objects in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Let's suppose the following tables:

**TableA**

```
TableAId int, PK, non-null
Name     varchar(50), non-null
```

**TableB**

```
TableBId int, PK, non-null
Name     varchar(50), non-null
```

**TableAToTableB**

```
TableAToTableBId int, PK, non-null
TableAId         int, FK, non-null
TableBId         int, FK, non-null
```

Then let's say I wanted a view like this to bind for display:

```
SELECT a.TableAId, 
       a.Name,
       COUNT(*) AS CountOfTableAToTableBId
FROM   TableA a 
    INNER JOIN 
       TableAToTableB ab 
    ON a.TableAId = ab.TableAId
GROUP BY a.TableAId, a.Name
```

What is the easiest way to retrieve views like this in Entity Framework where it's easy to say that each row returned is still a TableA object? This should only return in one query to the database as well.

Basically I just want to return a TableA object with additional columns for display purposes, but internally it should still be accessed like a TableA object. Hope that makes sense.

I'm struggling with how Entity Framework attempts to deal with complex views of multiple objects in an efficient and easy to manage way.

Comment: If you have multiple rows in TableB that match on TableA then what is your unique key for the view? Entity Framework requires that you have a unique key, but that's not really possible when you do a join like you are doing here. The "easiest" way to do this in EF is to not do it at all. You can easily write a reusable query that pulls back these results.

Comment: @Dismissile The view would have TableAId as unique since it's just a view of how many rows are in TableAToTableB for each TableA row. If I don't want database objects (sp's or views) to do this, how is it done in EF?

Comment: The easiest way to use `Entity Framework` is to never use the keywork `join`. Take a look at the `.Include(Expression<Func>)` monad. Otherwise you would want to concrete out those models.

Comment: I guess I don't see the benefit in having this as an entity instead of a query that can be executed.